# web3js does not send decimal values

Tags: web3js

Can someone help me with this problem I'm already racking my brain, I have a web3j script for metamask that the person chooses the value they want to send but doesn't accept decimals only whole numbers (ex: 1, 2, 3, 4), and I need that accept decimal numbers like (0.1, 0.2, 0, 3 .....), can someone help me solve this?

[image]

```html
   <body class="container"> 
    <div class="form-group ">
            <input class=" form-control" id="pay" type="text" placeholder="ENTER THE AMOUNT"/>
            <button class="btn btn-success" id="paySm">BUY NOW</button></div>        
    </div><hr/>
</body>
<script>
var instance;
var web3;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".success").hide(); $(".bal-success").hide(); $(".tx-success").hide();
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {  // alert("web3 detected");
    startApp(web3);
  }
function startApp(web3) {
    window.ethereum.enable();
    web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
    console.log(web3.eth.defaultAccount)
    var rinkebyABI= JSON.parse('[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address payable","name":"addr1","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"fundtransfer","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"Extron","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"success","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"balance","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]');
    EtherContract = web3.eth.contract(rinkebyABI);
    var rinkebyInstance = EtherContract.at('0x2052757Ef64B07ACa345E003208610A8E0968998');
   
    
    instance = rinkebyInstance;
    }
})

$(document).on("click", "#paySm", function(){
    var amt = $("#pay").val();
    var wei = parseInt(amt)*1e18;
    console.log("Amt: "+ amt);  
    console.log("Default Account: "+ web3.eth.defaultAccount); 
    console.log("Wei: "+ wei);  
    
    instance.Extron({from: web3.eth.defaultAccount, value: wei, gas: '299999', }, 
        function(err, transactionHash) {
            if (!err) console.log("Hash: "+ transactionHash);
            $(".success").text("transaction performed successfully");
            $(".success").show();
        })      
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue underlies in the following lines:

```
var amt = $("#pay").val();
var wei = parseInt(uint256)*1e18;
```

First `uint256` is undefined variable and let's assume that it should be replaced with `amt` then the other issue is that you're using `parseInt()` method which is instantly changing all decimals between 0 and 1 to 0. Change the lines with the following code and you should be able to achieve what you want:

```
var amt = $("#pay").val().trim();
var wei = parseFloat(amt) * 1e18;
```

Then to make it even better you can replace `var wei = parseFloat(amt) * 1e18;` with `var wei = web3.utils.toWei(amt);` and you don't have to worry for parsing and multiplying everytime when you need wei value.

Comment: I did it, thank you so much, you are awesome !!

Comment: Happy to help, you can accept my answer with the green check so others having the same issue can check it out.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is sending wei. Wei is the smallest non divisible unit. So you cannot send a fractional value.
Note that: 1 ether = 1,000,000,000,000,000,000 wei (10^18)

Comment: so there is no way for me to send a value less than 1?! : /